# Lazy loading with JBoss AS 6 and TransactionAttribute.NEVER?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions, jboss, lazy-loading

While, with Glassfish 3, I had no problem using lazy loading on no-transaction EJB methods, I can't figure out how to make it work with JBoss AS 6.

As a workaround, I can end my methods with entityManager.clear() , but it's not really sexy...

Does anyone know how to make hibernate lazy loading work with JBoss AS 6, on EJB methods annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER) ?

Comment: its basically the same problem as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428085/lazyinitializationexception-in-jpa-and-hibernate, hope that helps