# LazyInitializationException in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I know that this question has been ask numerous times here and across the internet and I have read through many of those answers but I still don't understand the proper way to solve this problem. I am experimenting with Spring MVC and JPA and every time I access a lazily loaded property I get a LazyInitializationException.

Here is some of the code I am experimenting with:

```
@Repository
public class MyDAO {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyDAO.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void logDOI() {
        DOI myDOI = em.find(DOI.class, Long.valueOf(1));

        // This line gives the expected output
        logger.info("Fetched DOI: " + myDOI.getDoiKey());

        // This line throws the LazyInitalizationException
        for(DOIMembership m : myDOI.getDoiMemberships()) {
            logger.info("Got DOI Membership id: " + m.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

The entity I am accessing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOI")
public class DOI implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DOI_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="DOI_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DOI_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    // Other properties omitted

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DOIMembership
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="doi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<DOIMembership> doiMemberships;

    public DOI() {
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Other Accessors Omitted

}
```

The entity referenced from DOI

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DOI_MEMBERSHIP")
public class DOIMembership implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DOI_MEMBERSHIP_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="DOI_MEMBERSHIP_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DOI_MEMBERSHIP_ID_GENERATOR")
    private long id;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DOI
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="DOI_ID")
    private DOI doi;

    @Column(name="GROUP_ID")
    private BigDecimal groupId;

    @Column(name="DATA_SET")
    private BigDecimal dataSetId;

    public DOIMembership() {
    }

    public BigDecimal getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getDataSetId() {
        return dataSetId;
    }

    public void setDataSetId(BigDecimal dataSetId) {
        this.dataSetId = dataSetId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(BigDecimal groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public DOI getDoi() {
        return this.doi;
    }

    public void setDoi(DOI doi) {
        this.doi = doi;
    }

}
```

The Spring MVC Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/summary")
public class DOISummaryController {
    @Autowired
    MyDAO myDAO;

    @RequestMapping()
    public String DOISummary() {
        myDAO.logDOI();

        return "home";
    }
}
```

My Spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/spring/root-context.properties, WEB-INF/spring/datasource-context.properties"  />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${Url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${Username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${Password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.myorg.doi.domain" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.myorg.doi" />

</beans>
```

And a stack trace, as requested:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/DOI] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:430)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at org.myorg.doi.dao.MyDAO.logDOI(MyDAO.java:27)
    at org.myorg.doi.web.DOISummaryController.DOISummary(DOISummaryController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.traceNextValve(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:116)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I you can see, I am trying to use pure JPA and only using Hibernate as a JPA provider.

I understand that the exception is caused by the session being detached from the entity. But, I thought that wouldn't happen if we are currently in a transaction, which should be the case since the logDOI method is annotated with @Transactional.

Of course, everything works perfectly if I change the FetchType to EAGER but it seems that I shouldn't have to do that.

I am also aware of OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter but it seems that I shouldn't have to use that either if I keep all access to my entities in a DAO annotated with @Transactional (or through some other means that I'm not aware of).

I think that I might be approaching this problem incorrectly but I don't know what the correct approach is. How is one supposed to effectively use lazily loaded properties?

Comment: It seems to be related to get the current Hibernate Session. Did you check you inject correctly the Hibernate Session in your configuration? You ... have the annotation `@Repository` in new version of Spring Framework, I use it for some DAO.

Comment: I think it is the same that `@Entity` you already use. Then, you should check that the deepth you have set in JPA properties are enough deep to load any `@Autowired` dependencies.

Comment: And did you inject the current Hibernate Session inside your JPA manager? 
Finally, I far prefer  using [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html)

Comment: @ThierryB I'm sorry, I am very new to Spring and JPA and I do not know enough to answer your questions. Could you be more specific? Also, since I am learning JPA I would prefer to learn the correct way to use it before I use things like OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to Shailendra I started to look closely at the transaction and noticed that the transaction was never starting. With that information I did some investigation and found this: [Spring @Transaction not starting transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561360/spring-transaction-not-starting-transactions). I put `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in my servlet-context.xml file and suddenly the transaction for logDOI started up and everything worked correctly; I no longer got the LazyInitializationException. I am not at all clear as to why that worked. Any information on that would be appreciated.

Update:

I figured it out. A critical piece of my problem was in the servlet-context.xml file. This is what it looked like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp.doi" />

</beans:beans>
```

The major problem was in that context:component-scan line. Spring MVC creates two context which beans are instantiated in: the root application context defined with the contextConfigLocation parameter in the web.xml file and the servlet context defined in the DispatcherServlet in the web.xml file. The servlet context could see the application context but not the other way around. Now, as a result of context:component-scan being defined in the servlet context and scanning the **entire** application namespace, my DAO was being instantiated in the servlet context. However, the transaction annotation scanning was being done in the application context and the AOP proxy stuff for it could not be done from there. Simply modifying the context:component-scan in the servlet context to scan only the MVC controllers (`<context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp.doi.web" />` fixed everything; the DAO was being created in the application context and properly setup for transactions.

Comment: Glad it helped you. I tried to dig further and it looks like if you put the name attribute for tx:annotation-driven, then that name should be explicitly mentioned in @Transaction annotation ( it has an attribute transaction-manager). If there is no name then the Spring assumes that the transaction manager is a bean with name equal to the attribute name of tx:annotation ( in your case “transactionManager”. The Spring transaction docs too suggest this.

Comment: Thank! This also solved it for me. After updating Spring 2.5 to 3.2 I created one XML file so I'was stuck with the LazyInitializationException for a day. After creating a separate DispatcherServlet xml(Servlet context) file the problem was solved. Many Thanks!

Comment: A best practice for two contexts in spring mvc application is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11471568/4344443 . You really needn't move the <tx:annotation-driven /> to servlet-context.xml, just keeping it in application-context.xml. And in your application.xml define this: <context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp.doi">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve this would be to first understand why and when the session is closed inspite of being under single transaction. And the best way for that would be to enable the hibernate (as you are using hibernate as JPA provider) logging level to DEBUG in log4j configuration and track where the sessions are closed. This would give you a clear picture. Although the stack trace suggests that the underlying session was closed but there are obviously no reason why ? You can post the relevant debug/info messages logged.

Also you can set up logging for spring framework to track the transaction management infrastructure

The logs give fairly good messages on when the underlying session was closed and transaction committed.

For e.g.,

```
opened session at timestamp: 13476520251
............
...........
after transaction begin
..............

select x,y,z from......
...............
...commit
..........
..flushing session
..after transaction completion
..closing session
```

Comment: Well, this is interesting. I enabled debug logging in my log4j config for org.hibernate and org.springframework.transaction. After that I  got exactly one line in my logs talking about transactions:

`DEBUG: 2012-09-17 09:51:55,976 org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'logDOI' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''`

It seems that the transaction is not even being started. I have no idea why. My configuration seems identical to the examples I have seen.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem, but inspired by your answer, I solve it. Here is it.

My application try to use Jpa Repository to handle the data in a rest controller, which turns out got the no session error. Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params) {
    Project project = Factory.project().build(params);
    project = repository.save(project);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)  and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s), we know that beans in servlet context can reference beans in the application context. So the TransactionManager can not access to this rest controller bean, resulting this error.

Solution, creating a middle layer bean application context between rest controller and repository, encapsulating those code. I try it, it works fine. Update the code later.

Answer (score 0):

First, for any dependency set with @Autowired, you must declare a Spring Bean foreach DAO you will use, and it will be injected at runtime.

Maybe these DAO need to have a sessionFactory reference like this:

```
<!-- a dao in which you inject your Hibernate SessionFactory bean by its own id -->
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.enterprise.model.dao.UserDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactoryId" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- activate the @Repository annotation -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Secondly, maybe you forget to add this inside your Spring XML configuration:

```
<!-- Add JPA support -->
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
```

Third, your interceptor stuff:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

Comment: I did that and I still get the same exception.

Comment: I have added some usefull things to load @Repository stuff.

Comment: Also, how is the DAO not declared as a spring bean? It is annotated with `@Repository` and the `@Autowired` annotation is picking it up correctly. The `logger.info("Fetched DOI: " + myDOI.getDoiKey());` line in logDOI is being executed properly with the correct output.

Comment: Why are you having me inject a Hibernate session into my DAO? I want to work exclusively with JPA and only use Hibernate as a JPA implementation. And isn't what you are having me do the same thing as using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation?

Comment: It is how I do but I don't have any example of my own with jpa here, check any tutorial about JPA and Hibernate as persitence provider [like these one](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/)