# lazyinitializationexception when session is not closed

Tags: java, hibernate, debugging, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate in my object and getting lazyinitializationexception even when session is not closed.

Here is the relation of the objects in issue. There are 3 Objects:

1. ObjectA
2. ObjectB
3. ObjectC

ObjectA includes ObjectB as FetchType=EAGER
ObjectB includes ObjectC as FetchType=LAZY

We are fetching ObjectA. So, because of eager fetch type, it is automatically fetching ObjectB.
But when I am trying to fetch ObjectC using ObjectB, it is giving this error.

The code is too big and proprietary. So, can't share the code.

Note:
1. All these operations are being done inside one transaction only.
2. I checked the logs and found out that session is not being closed.
3. I found similar link - [LazyInitializationException in JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428085/lazyinitializationexception-in-jpa-and-hibernate) I am using annotationDriven tag also in my code as suggested in this link.

I am not getting if why is it happening.

Comment: can you share with us the code / config / logging? thanks

Comment: I suppose you have put @Transactional on your service class?

Comment: @geert3: The code is too big and proprietary. So, can't share the code.

Comment: @StijnGeukens: Yes, I have put that.

Comment: "getting lazyinitializationexception even when session is not closed" - so how do you prove that? Because at the moment I can only assume that the session that the entity was loaded in IS closed, and you just don't understand why. I will of course fully believe you when you say that "a" session is open - but I don't believe you that it is the session in which the entity was loaded. Problems can already occur when you have a nested transaction situation for example.

Comment: if you can't share more information, we can't help you. Show the issue in a unit test and we can continue.

Comment: @Gimby Can you please give any example of how a nested transaction can cause this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

is my understanding is correct?

> ObjectA includes ObjectB as FetchType=EAGER ObjectB includes ObjectC
>   as FetchType=LAZY
>
> We are fetching ObjectA. So, because of eager fetch type, it is
>   automatically fetching ObjectB. But when I am trying to fetch ObjectC
>   using ObjectB, it is giving this error.

ObjectA.getObjectB = OK ? i mean no exception thrown or no error right?

then when you access ObjectC by ObjectB by :

1. ObjectB.getObjectC or
2. ObjectA.getObjectB.getObjectC ?

and you get an exception of LazyInitializationException.

Hibernate Documentation says that..

> A LazyInitializationException will be thrown by Hibernate if an
>   uninitialized collection or proxy is accessed outside of the scope of
>   the Session, i.e., when the entity owning the collection or having the
>   reference to the proxy is in the detached state.
>
> Sometimes a proxy or collection needs to be initialized before closing
>   the Session. You can force initialization by calling cat.getSex() or
>   cat.getKittens().size(), for example. However, this can be confusing
>   to readers of the code and it is not convenient for generic code.
>
> The static methods Hibernate.initialize() and
>   Hibernate.isInitialized(), provide the application with a convenient
>   way of working with lazily initialized collections or proxies.
>   Hibernate.initialize(cat) will force the initialization of a proxy,
>   cat, as long as its Session is still open. Hibernate.initialize(
>   cat.getKittens() ) has a similar effect for the collection of kittens.

from - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization

You have two option

Change `FetchType=LAZY` to `FetchType=EAGER` on your relationship between ObjectB and ObjectC

or use `Hibernate.initialize(ObjectC);`
to initialize the objectC before the transaction ends..

hope this will help you..