# Infinite json serialization in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have following mapping:

### 1

```
public class Content {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "content_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long contentId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    UserContent userContent;
     ....
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_content")
public class UserContent {
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "content"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "content_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long contentId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    Content content;
}
```

and following dao:

```
 public Set<UserContent> getAllContent() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return new HashSet<UserContent>(session.createCriteria(UserContent.class).list());
    }
```

when return result of this dao in controller method I see infinitie recursive json:

> [{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":{"contentId":1,"name":"DSC_0029.JPG","moderationStatus":"IN_PROGRESS","moderateComment":"","content":{"userContent":....

### 2

I tryed to change mapping like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

public class Content {
    ...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "content", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore        //added this annotation
    UserContent userContent;
    ....
```

result:

> HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a
>   collection of role: com.terminal.domain.TerminalUser.companys, no
>   session or session was closed (through reference chain:
>   java.util.HashSet[0]->com.terminal.domain.UserContent["user"]->com.terminal.domain.TerminalUser["companys"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily
>   initialize a collection of role:
>   com.terminal.domain.TerminalUser.companys, no session or session was
>   closed (through reference chain:
>   java.util.HashSet[0]->com.terminal.domain.UserContent["user"]->com.terminal.domain.TerminalUser["companys"])

### P.S.

I have read followig popular answer but I cannot struggle my problem - please help.

[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Since Jackson 2.0 you can use `@JsonIdentityInfo`.
Check [documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity)

**Updated**

```
...
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class Content {
    ...
}

...
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class UserContent {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailed answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Update :** 
**About Infinite Recursion.**

> You have Bidirectional Relationship right ? imagine json converts your
>   Content entity class then it has field of userContent and in
>   UserContent Entity class it has a content field also then it will
>   result infinite Recursion thats why you put @JsonIgnore in your
>   UserContent Field to ignore that field to avoid infinite recursion. - Secondo

I bet you have `private List<TerminalUser> companys;` inside of your Content entity class.

I lost on my bet. XD :))

Based in this line.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.terminal.domain.TerminalUser.companys,
```

just set the fetchType to Eager in `private List<TerminalUser> companys;` or just initialized it using Hibernate.initialized();

for more explanation refer to this link.  [lazyinitializationexception when session is not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27170469/lazyinitializationexception-when-session-is-not-closed/27185501#27185501)

Comment: UserContent have TerminalUser field and terminalUser have List<Companys> but I don't understand how does it related with JsonIgnore

Comment: thats why you are getting lazyinitialization exception you haven't initialize the list of company on your TerminalUser object

btw. @jsonIgnore is use to ignore some field in your entity class this is also use to avoid  `infinite recursive`.  You got lazyinitialization exception because json tries to convert all of the related field on your object/entity class and json found out that List<Companys> is not yet initialize.

Comment: if you dont need the `List<Companys>` just put @JsonIgnore also

Comment: I just encounter same problem weeks ago and thats what i found out.

Comment: Yes, know this problem but it appeared only after adding annotation  @JsonIgnore

Comment: when you put `@JsonIgnore` in a certain field it means that when Json converts your object that field will be ignored and not include in convertion process. lazyinitialization exception appears because @jsonIgnore solves your first problem about infinite recursion thing.

Comment: Hmm... looks like truth

Comment: You have Bidirectional Relationship right ? imagine json converts your Content entity class then it has field of `userContent` and in UserContent Entity class it has a `content` field also then it will result infinite Recursion thats why you put @JsonIgnore in your UserContent Field to ignore that field to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: so your current problem right now is to fix the lazyinitialization exception by changing its fetchtype to eager or use the Hibernate.initialize(yourCollection); in dao layer .

Comment: I just added @JsonIgnore for this field)

Comment: whats the result let me know :))

Comment: If I was able to help you Im happy to receive my first Accepted answer :)) XD TIA